# how to split array data in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net, split, datatables

I have a datatable that returns a column name location which is a combination of city,state and zipcode,i have stored that column values in an array. now i want to split the array data and store in another array.
here is the code but it is not working.

```
Dim eTemp As DataTable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "Location")
Dim s() As String
Dim Count As Integer = PortCodeTemp.Rows.Count - 1
ReDim s(0 To Count)
For i = 0 To Count
    s(i) = PortCodeTemp.Rows(i).Item("Location")
    For t As Integer = 0 To Count
        Dim items As String() = s.Split(",".ToCharArray())
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Where is defined PortCodeTemp and what relation has with the eTemp table. Finally Split is a method of a string instance not of an array of strings. This code cannot be compiled as is.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is it throwing an error (build or runtime)? Is it producing the wrong array?

Comment: I wouldn't store city,state,zipcode in the same column. That can cause a lot of trouble in the futur. I would suggest you always store them seperatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here

```
Dim items As String() = s.Split(",".ToCharArray())
```

because there is no Split method for an array.

I think you meant to split the string at index **i**, which is where you stored the string value of location.

```
Dim items As String() = s(i).Split(",".ToCharArray())
```

---

Update

I'm not sure why you're doing it this way but here is something you can try. Instead of using an array I just used a List(Of String) so there's no need to be doing a redim in every loop.

```
Dim allItems As New List(Of String)
For i = 0 To PortCodeTemp.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim location as String = PortCodeTemp.Rows(i).Item("Location")
    allItems.AddRange(location.Split(",".ToCharArray()))
Next
```

Therefore, allItems should contain everything.

Comment: Really appreciate your effort to give answers and help me, But can you please help me to find and store in an array values from location column for each row.

Comment: @son I'm not entirely sure what you mean. The items array will contain the different values in the location column for one row. You can then loop through that and add them into an array for all rows if that is what you mean.

Comment: Yes i want to do that only,but every time i am getting only one result in the array

Comment: @son I guess I am not explaining it well enough. I added an update in the answer, let me know if that is what you require.